# Unlock Row Only MySQL InnoDB

Tags: mysql

What is the correct way to unlock a single row in MySQL? I've seen people suggest Flush Table but doesn't that release all the locks on a table? I'm only interested in unlocking a specific row. I'm looking for the opposite of "SELECT * FROM t_1 WHERE id = '5' LOCK In READ MODE

Comment: If the table is MyISAM, only table level locking is supported.

Comment: Sorry I should have specified the storage engine.